# Convert bitmap to byte array android makes app crash

Tags: android, sockets, bitmap, arrays

I'm trying to send image between android devices using socket. At first, selected image will be converted to bitmap, and then transformed to byte[] to send, but the process handle of bitmap always makes application force close

Here is the code

```
File imgFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/beach.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = null;
try{
 fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
imageByte = stream.toByteArray();
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(imageByte);
os.flush();
```

When debugging on real device, the app always forced close at line bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
I did try other way: create buffer for bitmap and allocate ByteBuffer, but processing bitmap always causes crash like: bm.getByteCount() or even bm.getHeight()

Anyone please help me with this problem?

Otherwise, can anybody just list some other methods to send data(image, media...) on android, I'm making an interaction app which provides sharing data between users. Thanks a lot.

Comment: post your logcat to trace which line of code causes the app to force close

Comment: Why don't you just send the file instead?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, this is just a mistake on displaying Toast causing app crashed, silly me!!!

Comment: But still your approach is wrong. You want to send a jpg file to the other side. But you first place it in memory as a bitmap. The bitmap will use ten times more memory then a jpg. Then you write it to a byte array in memory. You need yet so much memory. Then you send the bytearray. So you send ten times more bytes then the original file contains. All a waist. Open an fileinputstream on the file instead and read small chunks and send them.

Comment: Thanks, I took this approach: open a FileInputStream fis on the file, then converted to byte[] using: fis.available(), and sent it using ObjectOutputStream, that should be better

Comment: Yes that is better but still not good. Why reading the whole file in memory? Do read/write in a loop.